# How to get Python to not encode my urls

Tags: python, url, encoding

I've got a simple script that opens a uri in the appropriate application. It's not a web browser (not http).

I've been using `webbrowser`, which opens it in the right application, but it url encodes everything, which is frustrating. There's another easy way to see my problem, by simply trying to open a google search:

```
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/#q=sdfs dfs')
```

This breaks because it try's to open:

```
https://www.google.com/%23q=sdfs%20dfs
```

And Google returns an error. I've been trying to figure out how to turn off url encoding, but haven't turned up anything. I'm not married to `webbrowser`, but whatever it is, it'd need to be able to open with different url types, `urllib` doesn't:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: jjur>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `https://www.google.com/#q=sdfs dfs` isn't valid -- you can't have a space anywhere in a url, and you can't put a query string after the '#'.  Fragment id's have to come last.

Comment: I know on the space, that was done of purpose to show the %20, the '#' though is placed there for me by google. If you go to google.com, search for something, you'll see it there too.

Comment: I see that now... and frankly I'm baffled why it looks like that, because the rfc seems to be saying the fragment should come at the end:  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5  I guess it's not really relevant to your problem, anyway.

Comment: I don't see anything in here that's doing url encoding https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/webbrowser.py so it might be your "not a browser" application that's doing it, rather than the webbrowser module.  It's also possible that the request is being proxied by your browser...

Comment: Ah, yea it's probably getting proxied. It's on OSX. This starts to really stretch my knowledge on the subject, but is there a way I can hand over a uri to the system and it decides where to send it, without this browser step? Through some magic the developers have set it up so any `jjur://` links get handled by this app. There was a simple API from Apple to follow, the delegate is just passed a string. Folks here have gotten a script in Ruby land to do this, without encoding, I'm move some of it over to Python and on trying to reproduce the results.

Comment: Though, back to the previous point, it'd be weird if it was just being proxied by Safari. Opening `https://www.google.com/#q=sdfs dfs` in Safari works just fine, but what happens here is the script has Safari try to open `https://www.google.com/%23q=sdfs%20dfs` -- seams like something else is handling the encoding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77758/discussion-between-1-618-and-inbetween).